# doubt about contourn of residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

How can I calculate the value of these integrals

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{we^{it(w+w_b)}}{w-w_a}dw\\$

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{we^{it(w+w_b)}}{w+w_a}dw$

where $w_a>0$ and $w_b>0.$

I would like to use the residue theorem, but I do not understand how to close the contours, could someone explain to me?

thanks

Comment: The first integral is divergent as it has a singularity at $w=w_a$

Comment: Apart from the fact that you need to specify how you define the first integral around $w=w_a$ (taking principal value or bypassing the pole from below or from above are few possible choices), none of these integrals are convergent at $\infty$ (at least for $t\in\mathbb R$), they oscilate. You can still define them in a way, for example the second one can be specified as

$$ \lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^\infty \frac{w}{w+w_a} e^{it(w+w_b)} e^{-\lambda w} dw$$
but again, this is only one possible way of giving them a specific value.

Comment: Contour integration won't work, these integrals (even when properly regularized) cannot be expressed with elementary functions. You'll need some special functions, for example integral sine ${\rm Si}(z)$ and integral cosine ${\rm Ci}(z)$.